# Show div next to li element of a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I need to design menus in  such a way so that submenus show up as show in image below [image]

Let us say that menu 1, 2, 3 should show corresponding div on right and menu 4,5 should show div container on left side of the menu as show in image below.

So far i have been able to manage to make it work to some extend but it is not perfect.

issues with this

1. I am able to show corresponding div next to sub menu x but it show it next to submenu while i want it show show up from the TOP of the menu sub menu contianer.
2. I want it to show first submenu as default select when one hover over parent menu, at present it doen't show submenu related text and image unless i hover over submenu.

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Q42hN/5/)

Below is the code.

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
                    <ul class="block">
                        <li><div class="div">This  block show some text and an image on the right side of the text </div></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
                    <ul class="block">
                        <li><div class="div">This  block show some text and an image on the right side of the text </div></li>
                    </ul>
               </li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
                    <ul class="block-right">
                        <li><div class="div-right">This  block show some text and an image on the right side of the text </div></li>
                    </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
                    <ul class="block">
                        <li><div class="div">This  block show some text and an image on the right side of the text </div></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
                    <ul class="block">
                        <li><div class="div">This  block show some text and an image on the right side of the text </div></li>
                    </ul>
               </li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
                    <ul class="block">
                        <li><div class="div">This  block show some text and an image on the right side of the text </div></li>
                    </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Q42hN/5/)

I would appreciate help in this regarding i dont mind using jquery with it so to make it work properly and show.

Answer (score 2):

Like this `links helping you`

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fredthewebchap/maasz/)**

Comment: I wish it was that easy.. I want functionality close to what i have explained. example which you have shown is clean and bit easy. what is making it difficult for me is that it should show a contianer div under parent menu with 500px width and text should change when one hover over submenus. I like you sub menu design it is clean...